# Why is Varchar a lower data type precedence than INT?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, errors, implicit-conversions

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    MyInt INT
)

INSERT INTO #a VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

CREATE TABLE #b
(
    MyVarchar VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #b VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('ten')
```

If I run the following query;

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #a
        LEFT JOIN #b
            ON #a.MyInt = #b.MyVarchar
```

SQL Server has to perform an implicit conversion as `#a.MyInt` and `#b.MyVarchar` are mismatched data types. Due to [data type precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the column with the lowest type precedence (#b.MyVarchar) is converted to the type of the higher precedence (INT)

This means the query above becomes equivalent to

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #a
        LEFT JOIN #b
            ON #a.MyInt = CONVERT(INT,#b.MyVarchar)
```

and both fail because there is a value in `#b.MyVarchar` which is an invalid value for an `INT` column.

My question is why does `VARCHAR` have a lower precedence than `INT`? if it were the other way round, the implicit conversion would succeed but instead we get a query which errors. Why would an error be preferred to a successful execution? My guess would be something along the lines of this being more a "defensive" mechanism on SQL Server's part - it prefers an error and therefore needing to user to explicitly decide what they want to do rather than give perhaps unexpected query results without the user being made aware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since SQL Server is a RDBMS these are optimized for applications sending SQL queries against properly defined tables.

Lowering the data type precedence of varchar enables the engine to avoid implicit conversions on the column expressions when evaluating a query that sends arguments as literal strings or varchar parameters:

```
select * 
from someTable
where SomeIntColumn = '1'
```

or

```
where SomeDateColumn = '2024-01-01'
```

In both of these common cases we avoid converting every row's value and enable indexed lookups with this strategy.

Also this makes queries of the form

```
where SomeIntColumn = 'not convertable to int'
```

fail instead of returning zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

We have two possible scenarios to compare string with integer:

- convert string into integer (one multi-tick operation) and then do a single-word comparison (one tick). "Word" and "tick" here are in assembler meaning.
- convert integer into string (one multi-tick operation) and compare two strings (another multi-tick operation)

We can say that the first scenario is faster, because there is just one multi-tick operation.

It is a very rare case when we need to do such comparison, so even if we know that the second scenario gives more flexibility - the need for it is very rare. So speed wins.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why does VARCHAR have a lower precedence than INT?

Also this way ,sql engine exhibit `Strongly Typed` nature of programming.By defining data type such as `datetime`,`INT`,`BIT` it enforces firm restriction on data and maintain `data integrity`.It exhibit the characteristic of `RDBMS`.

So above data sample query should defintly fail.